# Does p4v client have/allow to create a shortcut to copy local file path into clipboard?

Tags: perforce

In the older perforce windows client (p4Win, deprecated in 2008), there used to be a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shortcut that would copy selected file's local path (as opposed to depot path) into clipboard. It worked from  Changelist panel, depot view panel, from anywhere. In p4v I have to switch to workspace panel, select a file, and only then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copies local path into clipboard. Is there a way to have a single keyboard shortcut in p4v to achieve similar behaviour and copy local file path from any panel?

Comment: Might make more sense on stackoverflow actually